# thread for string line; whilst reading a file

Tags: c++, multithreading, debugging, lldb

I have the following code in a class for reading a file. It was working correctly when it was in the main file, but started showing a thread when I put it in a function in another class. It automatically shows this code when debugging:

```
_LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY
    void __zero() _NOEXCEPT
            {
            size_type (&__a)[__n_words] = __r_.first().__r.__words;
            for (unsigned __i = 0; __i < __n_words; ++__i)
                __a[__i] = 0;
        }
```

This is the class:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream> // Stream class to both read and write from/to files
#include <string>
#include "CLevels.h"

using namespace std;

CLevels :: CLevels(){

}

int CLevels :: loadFile(){
    std::string line;
    ifstream myfile ("//Users//mariahsaliba//Documents//School//University//Second Year//Semester 1//CCE 2111 - Object Oriented Programming//Assignment_2013_CCE2110//Assignment//Levels.txt");
    if (myfile.is_open())
    {
        while ( getline (myfile,line) )
        {
            cout << line << '\n';
        }
        myfile.close();
    }

    else cout << "Unable to open file\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Any help please?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by: "started showing a thread". Can you explain it a little more?

Comment: can you show the call trace?

Comment: You don't need to double forward slashes.

Comment: first i tried this code in the main program, then when i closed it in a function in another class, build succeeded but a library opens on code shown above _zero()... and therefore it shows the thread

Comment: #include <iostream>
#include <fstream>  // Stream class to both read and write from/to files
#include <string>

#include "CLevels.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    CLevels *levels = new CLevels;
    levels->loadFile();
    
    return 0;
}

Answer (score 1):

A lot of the standard C++ library functions are inlined even in debug (unoptimized, `-O0`) mode.  When you're stepping through your own C++ code over a `std::string` ctor or method on a string object, the code to implement that is often inlined right into your function.  The debugger *sees* that inlined code from the C++ header files right there.

lldb tries to hide this inlining from you so you don't see any of it by default.  But it's rather tricky, and if the line table entries in the debug information aren't exactly correct, sometimes it will look like you've stepped into the middle of a function from the standard library.

Just hit next / Step Over here and I bet you will return to your actual method's code.